# Add a cyclically control to the next lastChild element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

This is my idea:

```
var add = document.getElementById('div');
while(add.childElementCount>0){
    add+='.lastChild';
    if(typeof add.childElementCount === 'undefined'){
        add.appendChild(myNewChild);
        break;
    }
}
```

I need to add lastChild every time I run the cycle because I need to know the last child of the last container.
I know that add `add+='.lastChild';` Does not charge any instruction is that it is always undefined because it is not a property but a string but how do I add a real property...
I hope it is understood, I would replace `add+='.lastChild';`, with real statement that this add properties.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to add lastChild every time I run the cycle because I need to know the last child of the last container.

You can use the [:last-child CSS pseudoselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child):

```js
// Directly from MDN
```

```css
li:last-child {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This item is not limed.</li>
  <li>Also not this one.</li>
  <li>This item is! :)</li>
</ul>
```

If you need to look for it in JavaScript for some reason, you can still use

```
let item = parent_element.querySelector(':last-child');
```

as in

```js
console.dir(document.querySelector('li:last-child'));
```

```css
li:last-child {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This item is not limed.</li>
  <li>Also not this one.</li>
  <li>This is the last child li!</li>
</ul>
```